# Installing Sitecore SXA package spins endlessly on cloud

Tags: sxa, installation, packages

We have **Sitecore 9.3 PAAS Azure** environment and want to add SXA. We had to install **PowerShell 6.1** version as the **compatible version 6.0** gave errors and installation would not complete. We were following the steps here: **[https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/38B65D623B914C108A56C56FE011BD53.ashx](https://dev.sitecore.net/%7E/media/38B65D623B914C108A56C56FE011BD53.ashx)**

But then when we try to install the SXA package, it never completes and keeps spinning though as per the logs, package has been installed and all features seem to work fine. Still we are concerned as the package installation does not complete properly. We have retried it in multiple environments - qa, uat, etc with the same outcome. However the package installation does complete on local laptop. Please advise if you have faced similar situation and how did you resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's important to note that the logs can provide valuable information that can help you troubleshoot the issue. You may want to check the logs to see if there are any error messages or warnings that indicate why the installation is not completing properly.

- **Powershell Version**: One possible cause of this issue could be related to the version of
  PowerShell that you're using. While you mentioned that you installed
  PowerShell 6.1 because the compatible version 6.0 gave errors, it's
  worth noting that Sitecore 9.3 requires PowerShell 5.1. You may want
  to try uninstalling PowerShell 6.1 and installing PowerShell 5.1 to
  see if this resolves the issue.
- **Clear Sitecore caches**: Clear the Sitecore caches to ensure that any
  potential caching issues are not causing the problem. This can be
  done by accessing the Sitecore Control Panel and navigating to the
  "Cache" section. Clear all the caches and try reinstalling the SXA
  package.

If neither of these solutions works, it may be worth reaching out to     Sitecore support for further assistance. They may be able to provide     additional guidance on how to troubleshoot the issue and resolve it.